# Add RadioButton inside RadioGroup in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-radiogroup

I've been trying to add radio buttons inside a radio group in a listview. 
So, if I click a radio button it checks it but if I click another one, it doesn't remove the previous selection. I'm a beginner in android so forgive me If I'm doing something terribly wrong.

### This is my Main Activity and I have the radio group outside the list

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/car_list_radio_group">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/vehicle_list"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>
```

### This is my custom view for each item on the list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/car_selected"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:buttonTint="@color/tesla_red"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vin"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/car_selected"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### This is my adapter for the list

```
private final class VehiclesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater inflter;
        ArrayList<VehicleItem> vehiclesArray;

        public VehiclesAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<VehicleItem> items) {
            vehiclesArray = items;
            inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return vehiclesArray.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return Long.parseLong(vehiclesArray.get(position).getId());
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            VehicleHolder holder;
            VehicleItem vehicleItem = vehiclesArray.get(position);

            if (convertView == null) { // if convertView is null
                convertView = inflter.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_item, parent, false);

                holder = new VehicleHolder();
                holder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.car_selected);
                holder.vin = convertView.findViewById(R.id.vin);

                // initialize views
                convertView.setTag(holder);  // set tag on view
            } else {
                holder = (VehicleHolder) convertView.getTag();
                // if not null get tag
                // no need to initialize
            }

            if(vehicleItem.getId().equals(currentVehicle)){
                holder.name.setChecked(true);
            }

            holder.name.setText(vehicleItem.getName());
            holder.vin.setText(vehicleItem.getVin());

            //update views here
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

If you need to see something else please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`RadioGroup` is a `LinearLayout` and is meant to have `RadioButton` children in order to handle check/uncheck properly. You will have to drop it and handle the check/uncheck logic yourself from the adapter.

Comment: Can you guide a little bit more with your solution? Thanks.

Comment: Your custom view layout looks fine, from your Activity layout remove the `RadioGroup`. You can handle clicks in the adapter class in such a way that when a click on a radio button happens, all the vehicles other than the one whose view was just clicked (current vehicle) get unchecked. Also, a nice improvement would be to use `RecyclerView` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

add this in your list_item.xml
You will get radioGroup in each row
And remove RadioGroup from main_activity.xml

hope this will help you...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
android:backgroundTint="#ffffff">

<RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/car_list_radio_group">
  <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/car_selected"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:buttonTint="@color/tesla_red"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/car_not_selected"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_torightof="@+id/car_selected" 
    android:buttonTint="@color/tesla_red"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
</RadioGroup>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/vin"
    android:layout_width="183dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/car_selected"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```